# Summernote disappears after ajax update

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, summernote

I'm using Summernote with JSF, in this way:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Texto</label>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{cursoMB.questao.questao.texto}"
                    disabled="#{cursoMB.questao == null}"
                    styleClass="summernote form-control" />
            </div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
jQuery('.summernote').summernote({
     height: 300,                 // set editor height

      minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
      maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor

      focus: false                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote      
});
```

Everything works fine, but when I execute the following `commandLink` the summernote disappears transforming in a simple `inputTextArea` without design:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{cursoMB.inserirQuestao()}"
                styleClass="btn btn-default" title="clique para inserir a questão">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="divTeste divQuestao"
                    onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') { 
    document.getElementById('inputTextOrdemQuestao').focus() } }" />
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
            </h:commandLink>
```

I noted that this happens because ajax is rendering my page again. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused because the JavaScript-manipulated piece of HTML is being replaced by the original server-generated HTML without it being JS-manipulated once again afterwards.

You've basically 2 options:

1. Simply don't ajax-update the JS-manipulated piece of HTML. Just explicitly update only the parts which *really* need to be updated, e.g. only the `<h:message>` component associated with the input field.
2. Or, if that's not an option, e.g. because you need to redisplay the submitted value because you're using some converter which manipulates the submitted value, then you need to explicitly re-execute that JS-manipulation when that piece of HTML is ajax-updated. In your specific case, it boils down to calling `jQuery('.summernote').summernote(...)` once again during the `success` event.

#### See also:

- [JSF/PrimeFaces ajax updates breaks jQuery event listener function bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400624/primefacess-partial-update-breaks-jquery-event-binding/)
- [Ajax not working right in JSF with a jquery slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147320/ajax-not-working-right-in-jsf-with-a-jquery-slide/)

Comment: For me the only possible solution is number 2, because i should update this textArea, so number 1 is discarded. I will try and come back here.

Comment: where can i put this jQuery ? I can't find the success event on ajax. How can i do it ?

Comment: @Shelly: Uh, so you didn't wrote the code in the question yourself? You'd better not copypaste code without understanding any tiny part of it ...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake i already implemented the "sucess" event on ajax. thanks BalusC